# Android: Reading a serializable file from another java app

Tags: java, android, serialization

As the title says I have a java program that will make a serializable file. I have read that the package needs to be the same which it is. So both of the classes are the same and they are in the same package and both projects also have the same name but I keep getting a stream corruption exception. I have also tried doing a fix by overriding the method in the Stream reader which also didn't work. Any ideas on how to be able to read my file would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: The same code generates not the same class.

I'd recommend to use something like a [DataOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) / [DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), if possible. It's more stuff you have to do on your own, but then it's guaranteed that you can write and read your data without problems on any platform and even using other languages such as Python, C, C++, and so on.

~ Morph